# SQLNestedException Exception - Native SSPI library not loaded

Tags: java, exception, sspi

I am getting the exception below in my server logs.  What does it mean and how do i fix it?

```
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (I/O Error: SSO Failed: Native SSPI library not loaded. Check the java.library.path system property.)
```

Answer (score 2):

Please add more detail in your question.

This seems to be a common jTDS error that occurs when connecting to a SQL server using windows authentication. If that is the case try adding `x86/SSO/ntlm.dll` (or the equivalent variant for your server architecture) from the jTDS distribution into the java.library.path by using

`-Djava.library.path=path/to/dll` on jvm startup